# Trying to use Serial to communicate between two D1 Mini's

Tags: serial

I'm trying to connect two D1 Mini's together as a POC.
There is a switch on one and a 7 segment display on the other

I have the pins setup from TX>RX and RX>TX

First ESP8266:

```
int SWITCH_PIN = D5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SWITCH_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  
  if(digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN) == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println(1);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(0);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
  }
}
```

Second ESP8266:

```
#include "DigitLedDisplay.h"
DigitLedDisplay ld = DigitLedDisplay(D6, D5, D0);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  ld.setBright(10);
  ld.setDigitLimit(8);
  
  for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    ld.printDigit(i);
    delay(25);
  }
  
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  if(Serial.read() == 1)
  {
    ld.printDigit(11111111);
  }
  else if (Serial.read() == 0)
  {
    ld.printDigit(22222222);
  }
  else
  {
    ld.printDigit(33333333);
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell the second ESP8266 isn't getting anything from the first. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: updated with a questions now

Comment: `Serial.println(1);` sends '1', not 1, so use `Serial.read() == '1'`

Comment: Sigh...
Thanks for that
I actually get the correct data back sometimes, but the output seems to swap between correct and the "else" status constantly

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj) it was an easy fix

Missing quotes around the text and changing some code

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
  }
  if(incomingByte == '1')
  {
    ld.printDigit(11111111);
  }
  else if (incomingByte == '0')
  {
    ld.printDigit(22222222);
  }
}
```

adding "if (Serial.available() > 0)" works to make it only update when the serial buffer is full

The delay was also causing issues with where it was located so just removed that

Comment: this will ld.print every loop if incomingByte is '0' or '1'